# Program not writing to dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple program that opens a file, splits it into single word lines (for ease of use) and creates a dictionary with the words, the key being the word and the value being the number of times the word is repeated. This is what I have so far:

```
infile = open('paragraph.txt', 'r')
word_dictionary = {}
string_split = infile.read().split()


for word in string_split:
    if word not in word_dictionary:
        word_dictionary[word] = 1
    else:
        word_dictionary[word] =+1
infile.close()
word_dictionary
```

The line `word_dictionary` prints nothing, meaning that the lines are not being put into a dictionary. Any help?

The paragraph.txt file contains this:

```
This is a sample text file to be used for a program. It should have nothing important in here or be used for anything else because it is useless. Use at your own will, or don't because there's no point in using it.
```

[I want the dictionary to do something like this, but I don't care too much about the formatting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7rV0.png)

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted program dies due to a private file.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `read` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: Start by changing =+ to +=

Comment: Two things: `=+` should probably be `+=`, and to print, you should do `print(word_dictionary)`

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values.  What is in string_split?

Comment: Look into the `collections` library, specifically `Counter` which you can find [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Using `word_dictionary = collections.Counter(string_split)` will save you a lot of heartache.

Answer (score 2):

Two things. First of all the shorter version of
`num = num + 1`

is

`num += 1`

not

`num =+ 1`

**code**

```
infile = open('paragraph.txt', 'r')
word_dictionary = {}
string_split = infile.read().split()


for word in string_split:
    if word not in word_dictionary:
        word_dictionary[word] = 1
    else:
        word_dictionary[word] +=1
infile.close()
print(word_dictionary)
```

Secondly you need to print `word_dictionary`

Comment: Weird, my textbook just uses the name of the dictionary to print.

Comment: Well then it's fine. But for most IDE's use print so its good practice.

Comment: Inside the python interactive shell, just typing a variable name will print it.  But in any other context (an IDE, a standalone script, etc.) you need to use `print()`.